# Preview opening-brace code when hover over closing-brace in Visual Studio (C++)

Tags: visual-studio, editor, curly-braces

On *extremely* rare occasions, when I hover my mouse over a closing brace in Visual Studio, a floating window appears that displays the code fragment that is just before the opening brace. For example, it might show, `if(x==1) {`.

How do I enable this behavior?

(FWIW, I do know about, and use, the `Ctrl+]` keyboard shortcut to jump between the opening and closing braces, but the preview window reduces my need to do this.)

Answer (score 0):

Duh! The preview window appears when you hover the mouse over one of the vertical lines that identifies begin/end braces, not when you hover it over the ending brace (as I mistakenly thought).

[image]